# Statistics on number of view

Tags: discussion, request

Can any moderator give me statistics on average number of views on questions ? I mean histogram showing frequency of number of views on questions. I just wanted to know how many people view/read any question on average. My guess is histogram peak will be at number which is almost equal to active members. Apologies if it is not possible due to SE policies.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, the number of views of specific questions will partially be a function of their age. Even so, most questions are probably mostly viewed when they are posted, or when later edits bump them in the activity queue. Quite few questions receive high view counts.

Either way, the information you're asking for (view counts of questions) can be found at http://data.stackexchange.com. [This](http://data.stackexchange.com/biology/query/edit/387936#graph) is a quick and crude fork I've made of an earlier query (previously on Q/A scores), which I ***think*** is showing the number of views (xaxis) against count (yaxis). I'm not used to writing SQL queries though. Click Run query and the graph tab so see a rather noisy plot (found below), which has a peak around 50 views (change the MinViews and MaxViews arguments to see parts of the plot more clearly)

[image]

Comment: Wow ! I didn't know about queries. thanks :)

Comment: @Dexter Yes, http://data.stackexchange.com/ can be very cool and useful if you know SQL or find the right queries. Here are for instance queries for [users with highest average answer scores](http://data.stackexchange.com/biology/query/952/top-500-answerers-on-the-site), [up/down vote ratio per user](http://data.stackexchange.com/biology/query/300464/most-evil-users) and [the highest voted comments](http://data.stackexchange.com/biology/query/241390/most-highly-voted-comments).